# Changing the configuration file in current use

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

Service fabric allows you to run the cluster with various configurations:

[image]

**How do I switch the cluster to run under a different configuration file on my localhost?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd say you have to remove the existing cluster first. For instance, if we consider 'Switch cluster mode' button that is available in SF Local Cluster Manager, then here is what it does according to the documentation -

> When you change the cluster mode, the current cluster is removed from
>   your system and a new cluster is created. The data stored in the
>   cluster is deleted when you change cluster mode.

So here is the path that should work for you -

1. Run RemoveServiceFabricCluster.ps1 to remove Service Fabric from each machine in the configuration(the one that you'll pass as a parameter to this command)
2. Run CleanFabric.ps1 to remove Service Fabric from the current machine
3. Run CreateServiceFabricCluster.ps1 passing this time a new config file

Comment: thank you very much, that's what i did, and wasn't succesful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45987317/how-to-remove-a-servicefabric-cluster

Comment: @l--''''''---------''''''''''''
Yeah, seems like you've run CleanFabric.ps1 in the beginning while you should've run RemoveServiceFabricCluster.ps1 instead. I did have more or less the same issue and it took me a while to get things up and running again. To my shame, I do not recall the exact steps but you should start with remove SF and SF SDK from your machine, and then you will need to reinstall them.

Comment: @l--''''''---------''''''''''''
Also, open up Resource Monitor and get rid of Fabric Event Trace Sessions as well as FabricCounters Collection Set.